# Using data (not METAdata) from a SSMS DB to drive biml in SSIS dtsx creation

Tags: biml

I need to be able to generate tasks in a data flow of a SSIS dtsx based on data stored in a SSMS DB table.
Basically, I have N (unknown, variable) sources and M (unknown, variable) destinations and I have a table T0 with MxN rows. Each row, using a bit B, specifies if I really need to send data from that specific source to that specific destination.
T0 is stored in a basic Database DB0 that is used for configuration.

Ideally, using BIML I want to script a dtsx that has a simple data flow (OLEDB Source -> OLEDB destination) FOR EACH row of T0 with B = 1. 
This dtsx generation must be driven by the data i find in T0.

Online I can find how to read METADATA from a DB but I can't find anyone talking about the much basic "reading data from a DB" and using these data in the BIML.
Do I need to handle the DB connection in the C# code in BIMLScript? How do I use/address the connection to DB0 in the c# code? (usually I would have this connection in a config file... in this case I need to refer to the connMgr from the C# script).

Comment: I looked for a solution for half an hour. Then 5 seconds after posting this, I found something like: 
<#DataTable tblSourceViews = ExternalDataAccess.GetDataTable(connMD, qrySourceViews);#>

I think this should allow to cycle with :

<# foreach (DataRow row in tblSourceViews.Rows) { #>

and get what I want

Comment: This is correct. Note that GetDataTable is just a convenience wrapper over the Microsoft ADO.NET APIs. If you need additional control over the queries you wish to run, you can use those APIs directly. There is a very large community of folks using those APIs on StackOverflow and elsewhere, so lots of help is available, as well.